# Plone plugin to enable insertion of predefined text into visual editor

Tags: tinymce, plone

Does a tinymce plone plugin exist for this?
I've done a quick search and come up empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.tinymcetemplates perhaps?